# Header idea help

Tags: header-footer

I'm new to LaTeX, i already created some documents, but I need your help to create a fancy cool header. I would like to create a header like this one :

[image]
Don't worry for the colors and the font, there are for the example. I will use the default Latex font.

I don't any idea how to do it, I found on the web that I should use some package like fancyhdr, graphicx... But I've never worked with this package. May somebody help me ? Tutorial, ideas, piece of code would be apprecied !

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. What you wish to do is definitely possible. But you will have to do your homework! Package fancyhdr is your friend. In order to insert an image, you would use a graphics package (graphicx is a good choice).

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer. I will try to persevere with fancyhdr if you think it's possible with this package!

Comment: See Bernard's answer, below. Apparently, you meant "title" instead of "header." A title appear on one page, and is usually prominent. A header appears on nearly every page at the top of a long document, and is less prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code with package `titleps`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=50mm, headheight=62pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx, adjustbox, microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
\sethead{}{\sffamily%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[b]{@{}l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\smash{\raisebox{-0.6\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{loupnorstein2}}}& date \\
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-2}
\addlinespace
& \huge \lsstyle BIG TITLE-MAIN TITLE \\
& theme of the paper\\
\addlinespace
\midrule[0.4pt]
\end{tabularx}%
}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! Good catch. Apparently the OP did not mean "header" but meant "title."

Comment: Probably you're right. I didn't even think of a possible confusion (it's getting late here…). Anyway, it's easy to modify – actually, it's simpler to make a title than a header – but I'll wait for a comment from the O.P.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's very clever to have used a table for the title, I did not think about it !

Answer (score 0):

In case that the OP what truly a header and not a title:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{headheight=2cm,headsep=2ex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent0pt
\fancyhead[CO]{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{example-image}%
\parbox[b]{.85\textwidth}{\raggedleft\sffamily\small 
date\\\rule[1ex]{.83\textwidth}{1pt}\\
{\huge BIG TITLE-MAIN TITLE}\\theme of the paper}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A big thank you for your answer, I've searching all the night to create multiple text head. You helped me a lot !